# Atmosphere @ManagedService @Inject not working

Tags: java, atmosphere, atmosphere.js

I have no idea, but my @Inject objects are not initialized with Weld inside of the ManagedService, my example is like this,

```
@ManagedService(path = "/chat") public class EntryPointWS {
  private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EntryPointWS.class);
  @Inject private ServiceFactory factory;
}
```

The same project or code, If i use a normal Servlet to access Weld will initialize the objects for me. Also, I'm running on Tomcat 8, it works fine with the Servlet injection though. Also, ServiceFactory is annotated as @ApplicationScoped.

Just to be clear, to add some more points,

- org.atmosphere.cdi.CDIObjectFactory (from the cdi pom) is defined in
- The @Inject doesn't work in AtmosphereInterceptorServices as well.

Comment: I found that the CDI spec doesnt have proper context sharing when we have Websockets, so I plan to use Guice for DI.

Answer (score 0):

have you enabled the CDI extension : https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere/wiki/Configuring-Atmosphere's-Classes-Creation-and-Injection

-- Jeanfrancois

Comment: Yes, I enabled that, the WIKI is actually giving wrong information, with latest 2.3.1 the implementation of CDIObjectFactory is different to what the WIKI says. So I included the pom dep and updated the init-param as follows,

  <init-param>
   <param-name>org.atmosphere.cpr.objectFactory</param-name>
   <param-value>org.atmosphere.cdi.CDIObjectFactory</param-value>
  </init-param>

Comment: And I'm using 2.3.1 of atmosphere framework, that should not be a problem right? In the samples I see there is a 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT,

Comment: @Fahad, have you solved this issue? I am also trying to use that pom dep and update init-param.